# Synchronize Buffered channel and Waitgroup

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I am having issue while using `waitgroup` with the `buffered` channel. The problem is `waitgroup`  closes before channel is read completely, which make my channel is half read and break in between.

```golang
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var err error

    start := time.Now()
    students := make([]studentDetails, 0)
    studentCh := make(chan studentDetail, 10000)
    errorCh := make(chan error, 1)

    wg.Add(1)

    go s.getDetailStudents(rCtx, studentCh , errorCh, &wg, s.Link, false)
    go func(ch chan studentDetail, e chan error) {
    
    LOOP:
        for {
            select {
            case p, ok := <-ch:
                if ok {
                    L.Printf("Links %s: [%s]\n", p.title, p.link)
                    students = append(students, p)
                } else {
                    L.Print("Closed channel")
                    break LOOP
                }
            case err = <-e:
                if err != nil {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }(studentCh, errorCh)
    wg.Wait()
    close(studentCh)
    close(errorCh)
    L.Warnln("closed: all wait-groups completed!")
    L.Warnf("total items fetched: %d", len(students))

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    L.Warnf("operation took %s", elapsed)
}
```

The problem is this function is `recursive`. I mean some `http call to fetch students` and then make more calls depending on condition.

```golang
func (s Student) getDetailStudents(rCtx context.Context, content chan<- studentDetail, errorCh chan<- error, wg *sync.WaitGroup, url string, subSection bool) {
    util.MustNotNil(rCtx)
    L := logger.GetLogger(rCtx)
    defer func() {
        L.Println("Closing all waitgroup!")
        wg.Done()
    }()

    wc := getWC()
    httpClient := wc.Registry.MustHTTPClient()
    res, err := httpClient.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        L.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    if res.StatusCode != 200 {
        L.Errorf("status code error: %d %s", res.StatusCode, res.Status)
        errorCh <- errors.New("service_status_code")
        return
    }

    // parse response and return error if found some through errorCh as done above.
    // decide page subSection based on response if it is more.
    if !subSection {
        wg.Add(1)
        go s.getDetailStudents(rCtx, content, errorCh, wg, link, true)
        // L.Warnf("total pages found %d", pageSub.Length()+1)
    }

    // Find students from response list and parse each Student
    students := s.parseStudentItemList(rCtx, item)
    for _, student := range students {
        content <- student
    }
 
    L.Warnf("Calling HTTP Service for %q with total %d record", url, elementsSub.Length())
}
```

Variables are changed to avoid original code base.

The problem is students are read randomly as soon as Waitgroup complete. I am expecting to hold the execution until all students are read, In case of error it should break as soon error encounter.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens here, but I find it easier to maintain a WaitGroup when `wg.Add(1)` and the corresponding `defer wg.Done()` appears really close to eachother in the code.

Comment: That's the good practice to use it near `defer wg.Done()` but I still not sure if that is the case. But I think if code has latency in writing to channel, then it should wait until all channels values are read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know when the receiving goroutine completes. The WaitGroup does that for the generating goroutine. So, you can use two waitgroups:

```
wg.Add(1)
go s.getDetailStudents(rCtx, studentCh , errorCh, &wg, s.Link, false)
wgReader.Add(1)
go func(ch chan studentDetail, e chan error) {
    defer wgReader.Done()
    ...
}
wg.Wait()
close(studentCh)
close(errorCh)
wgReader.Wait() // Wait for the readers to complete
```

Comment: This won't work. The problem is not separating 2 `goroutines` with different `waitgroup`. Since `goroutines` is recursive, so no check when it would be closed. The problem is `waitgroup` which closes before writing to the channel. I could limit the issue by reducing the buffer size of the channel but that's not expected,

Comment: The first waitgroup waits until the writers are done. The second is necessary to wait until the reader is done.

Comment: Thanks got the issue. I couldn't control `close` using a single `waitgroup`.  I have 2 separate `goroutines` and can control the execution of every piece of code now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using buffered channels you can retrieve the remaining values after closing the channel. You will also need a mechanism to prevent your main function from exiting too early while the reader is still doing work  ,as @Burak Serdar has advised.

I restructured the code to give a working example but it should get the point across.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type studentDetails struct {
    title string
    link  string
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var err error
    students := make([]studentDetails, 0)
    studentCh := make(chan studentDetails, 10000)
    errorCh := make(chan error, 1)

    start := time.Now()
    wg.Add(1)
    go getDetailStudents(context.TODO(), studentCh, errorCh, &wg, "http://example.com", false)

LOOP:
    for {
        select {
        case p, ok := <-studentCh:
            if ok {
                log.Printf("Links %s: [%s]\n", p.title, p.link)
                students = append(students, p)
            } else {
                log.Println("Draining student channel")
                for p := range studentCh {
                    log.Printf("Links %s: [%s]\n", p.title, p.link)
                    students = append(students, p)
                }
                break LOOP
            }
        case err = <-errorCh:
            if err != nil {

                break LOOP
            }
        case <-wrapWait(&wg):
            close(studentCh)
        }
    }
    close(errorCh)
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("operation took %s", elapsed)
}

func getDetailStudents(rCtx context.Context, content chan<- studentDetails, errorCh chan<- error, wg *sync.WaitGroup, url string, subSection bool) {
    defer func() {
        log.Println("Closing")
        wg.Done()
    }()
    if !subSection {
        wg.Add(1)
        go getDetailStudents(rCtx, content, errorCh, wg, url, true)
        // L.Warnf("total pages found %d", pageSub.Length()+1)
    }
    content <- studentDetails{
        title: "title",
        link:  "link",
    }
}

// helper function to allow using WaitGroup in a select
func wrapWait(wg *sync.WaitGroup) <-chan struct{} {
    out := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        out <- struct{}{}
    }()
    return out
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using the same snippet for controlling my `for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
wg.Add(1)
go func(){
    defer wg.Done()
    // I do not think that you need a recursive function.
    // this function overcomplicated.
    s.getDetailStudents(rCtx, studentCh , errorCh, &wg, s.Link, false)
}(...)

wg.Add(1)
go func(ch chan studentDetail, e chan error) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ...
}(...)

wg.Wait()
close(studentCh)
close(errorCh)
```

This should solve the problem. s.getDetailStudents function must be simplified. Making it recursive does not have any benefit.